# Multiple MAC addresses on a single network interface

Tags: windows, network-adapter, mac-address

Since the other question about this ([Multiple network interfaces on a single NIC in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/327139/)) only asks about different routing, I'm going to ask this again:

> Is there any way to create multiple virtual connections, each with its own MAC address, from a single network adapter on a Windows machine?

I know Linux supports this. I basically need to simulate to the network, that one computer is actually two computers, each with different MAC and therefore IP address.

Previously I have done this with another USB ethernet adapter, but this is no longer the option.

Note that this is NOT a wireless network, so Virtual Wifi adapters built-in Windows won't help for this.

Comment: As far as i know you can't do this with windows onboard tools. You can try using the Software Router/Switch/Bridge from Vmware or Virtualbox, don't know if this will work as expected but there you can give a virtual PC an own Macadress but bridge it to the Networkcard of the Host so maybe there is a way to use this Mechanism. Maybe also the aproach mentioned here https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=31007 will help you.

Comment: There is a way to do it when configuring VMs in Hyper-V. Basically, the adapter becomes a virtual switch. Each VM gets its own virtual NIC with its own MAC address. To the outside world, the one physical adapter looks/behaves like an array of adapters, each with its own MAC and IP address. When using Hyper-V this is all done using the Hyper-V Manager (or equivalent). I don't know if/how it can be done through ipconfig to achieve the result you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP, 2K, or Server Editions, add a Microsoft Loopback Adapter. This gives you a separate (virtual) adapter, with it's own MAC and IP stack.

Comment: What if we need more than just one ?